# "Android version 4.2.2 - Unable to invoke wget to download file or via JAVA Socket."

Tags: wget

I am trying to use wget with my Android app, which targets Android v 4.2.2. I granted the app Internet permission thru the AndroidManifest.xml file, but that did not solve the issue. I am still unable to download the file with wget command. I also tried to use a java socket to accomplish the connection to the server and download the file, however, that did not work. It seems that Android version 4.2.2 has restrictions on allowing network access thru Android apps. Could someone please help me identify a work around for getting network access so wget command can work from the Android app? Below is the code I am using to test the command.

```
private String runShellCommand() {
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("system/bin/wget -O /data/data/com.shell/filename http://url to the file");
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        int numRead;
        char[] buffer = new char[5000];
        StringBuffer commandOutput = new StringBuffer();
        while ((numRead = bufferedReader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            commandOutput.append(buffer, 0, numRead);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        process.waitFor();

        return commandOutput.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your goal seems to be to download a file rather than using wget correctly. To download the file within your app, which is the conservative and portable solution, try using the URL class and the HttpURLConnection class, or other classes available on android and suitable for downloading based on URLs.

Comment: I tried an example using HttpURL Connection class to download a file from a site, but that did not work. It seems like Android 4.1.1, which is the target device that I am using, has restrictions for an application network access. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I am not sure if android permissions are propagated from your app's process to the wget process. That might be the reason that wget does not work. I would forget this wget stuff alltogether. This is the approach you would use in a bash script in linux. It is not the straight forward approach for an android application.

Comment: Try HttpURLConnection again. That's the way to go. Find out what did not work there. Post Exceptions etc. here. You said in your question "I granted the app Internet permission thru the AndroidManifest.xml file". Did you already do this when testing with HttpURLConnection?